# Stacking pairs of columns in Excel with PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table generated in power query that is currently in the following format

| A | Key1 | Value1 | Key2 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | E1 |

I want

| A | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 |
| A1 | D1 | E1 |

How can this be achieved in power query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from Peter works, or to make it more generic:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
base=1,   // # leading columns that will repeat
group=2,  // followed by groups of 2 columns
Combo = List.Transform(List.Split(List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base),group), each List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base) & _),
#"Added Custom" =List.Accumulate(
        Combo, 
        #table({"Column1"}, {}),
        (state,current)=> state & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source, current)),1)
)
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Reference the original table, remove columns 4 and 5 and rename the remaining columns to A, Key and Value.
2. Reference the original table again, remove columns 2 and 3 and rename the remaining columns to A, Key and Value.
3. Append the 2 above queries